# Vertical align button in input

Tags: html, css

I am placing a button, with an icon, inside an input, see here: 
 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/hak4782y/24/)

```
<form>         
  <input type="text">     
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

form {
  width: 400px;
}

input {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -48px;
  padding: 12px;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;  
}

i {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

How can I vertically align the button with the `red outline`,  inside the input with the `green outline`?

From my attempt shown above, what is missing to achieve the required output?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` or `vertical-align: sub;`

Comment: It does not become centered with vertical-align: middle; or sub ... At least it does not seem to be.

Comment: on both element of course

Comment: have u tried to use position absolute on the button so it would behave as a block element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that solved it: https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/hak4782y/28/

Comment: @K.C. Yes, same example with absolute positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/zup3b24e/32/ ... Which one would you go for? I usually choose not to use absolute positioning but in this case I am not sure yet which approach should I use.

Comment: How about set `display: flex` to `form`?

Comment: @MiguelMoura for unknown heights, it's common to use position relative/absolute to position the child element. Here is an existing example I have that doesn't use position absolute, https://jsfiddle.net/kendra_chu/d9jgzwLn/

Answer (score -2):

pls try this css

```
<style>
form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```